# variable don't take value into bash linux script

Tags: linux, bash

I have the next fragment code from an bash script and for some reasone $line don't take any value for the seccond line.

```
cat address.txt | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
echo $line
 /opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set firewall group address-group ag-Blacklist address $line #here we dont have value for it
done;
```

content of the address.txt (only one line)

> 96.64.59.185

Output from my script:

> ./script.sh
>    96.64.59.185  ./script.sh: line 9: 13990 Segmentation fault      /opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set firewall group 
>   address-group ag-Blacklist address $line

Can someoane help me to understand why?
Thanks

Comment: `read line || [[ -n $line ]]` -> `read line && [[ -n $line ]]`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `...[[ -n $line ]]` ? When `read` fails, it will assign the empty string to `line`, so that check will never be true.  Are you trying to do: `while read line; do test -z "$line" && continue ...`?

Comment: @KamilCuck i change || with && and issue is same

Comment: @William Pursell i want to read each line from txt file until the end, each line contain an ip or an cidr

Comment: Could be your file has unprintable characters, like carriage return/dos line endings and an empty line. Check your file with `cat -v address.txt`

Comment: @KamilCuk well the problem it's not there because check the output ./script.sh
96.64.59.185
./script.sh: line 9: 13990 Segmentation fault      /opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set firewall group address-group ag-Blacklist address $line

Comment: Can you add `address.txt` contents to your question, as well as the exact output you're receiving?

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks for this tips, i add it into my original post

Answer (score 0):

The `-n` test does not make sense. To read a loop line by line, just do a

```
while read line
do
   echo Read line "'$line'"
   ...
done <address.txt
```

If the loop still processes one line only, the input file has just one line (test it with `wc -l <address.txt`).

Of course you can skip empty lines, if you want to:

```
while read line
do
   if [[ -n $line ]]
   then
     echo Process line "'$line'"
     ...
   else
     echo Empty Line skipped
   fi
done <address.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your interest for my problem but after i remove || [[- n $line ]] my issue still be the same. Please check my output    ./script.sh
'96.64.59.185'
./script.sh: line 9: 15494 Segmentation fault      /opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set firewall group address-group ag-Blacklist address "'$line'"
We can see there for the second line from while $line dosent take any value

Comment: What is the output, if you use **exactly** the code I have posted?

Comment: this one was the output ./script.sh '96.64.59.185' ./script.sh: line 9: 15494 Segmentation fault /opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper set firewall group address-group ag-Blacklist address "'$line'" We can see there for the second line from while $line dosent take any value

Comment: The segmentation fault is not important here, unless you have a `set -e` in your script. Actually, I would during debugging comment out the `set firefall` command and concentrate on reading the lines first. If you still get only the line `96.64.59.185`, it means that there are no more lines. I mean, reading through a file line by line is [standard task](https://www.shellhacks.com/bash-read-file-line-by-line-while-read-line-loop/); this is not rocket science. Copy one from the link mentioned, and once it runs, adapt it successively to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found finnaly an solution who work fine
Let me share with you

```
  cfg="/opt/vyatta/sbin/vyatta-cfg-cmd-wrapper"

$cfg begin
$cfg delete firewall group address-group ag-Blacklist
$cfg set firewall group address-group ag-Blacklist description "Designated threat addresses"

for line in $(cat /home/address.txt)
 do
  echo $line
  $cfg set firewall group address-group ag-Blacklist address ${line}
 done;

$cfg commit
$cfg end
```

Like this work fine without any problem.
Thanks for all interest guys.